# How to connect Android Application to SSL server when you have a CA that isn't trusted by the system?

Tags: java, android, ssl, ca

I’m trying to download images from a website which is secured with SSL. Downloading images is successful when I run the App on API 23(Android 6.0) or above, but when the App runs on lower APIs, I get **SSLHandshakeException** with the **“java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.”** message.

Comment: I'm trying to download images with Picasso.

Comment: try sharing your code here

Answer (score 0):

The solution is right under the fingertips. Try this link [Security with HTTPS and SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html). Complete solution is provided here

Answer (score 0):

> You can also use DownloadManager to download images from Url and save
>   to sdcard

DownloadImages(PictureURL, ImageSavePath);

```
public void DownloadImages(String theUrl, String thePath) {
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(theUrl);
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) myContext.getSystemService(myContext.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

        //Restrict the types of networks over which this download may proceed.
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        //Set whether this download may proceed over a roaming connection.
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
        //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
        String[] split = theUrl.split("/");
        //request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(myContext, mySdCardImagePath, split[split.length - 1]);
        //request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, split[split.length-1]);

        File destinationFile = new File(thePath, split[split.length - 1]);
        Uri uri = null;

        // naugat does not need provider here
        uri = Uri.fromFile(destinationFile);

        request.setDestinationUri(uri);

        //Set the title of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled).
        request.setTitle(split[split.length - 1]);
        //Set a description of this download, to be displayed in notifications (if enabled)
        request.setDescription(thePath);

        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);

        //Enqueue a new download and get the reference Id
        long downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        //Check_Image_Status(downloadReference);
    }
```

Comment: It's an e-commerce App and I want to put images in recycler view.I don't intend to download them into internal memory.

Comment: I have uploaded one more answer, I have used glide to load URL to images and does not face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Glide Image loader
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

> ```
> Use following code inside onBindViewHolder
> ```

```
    int defaultImagePath = R.drawable.default_thumb;
    int errorImagePath = R.drawable.damaged_image;
    holder.mImageViewContactItem.setImageResource(defaultImagePath);

    String uri = photoPath;
    loadImageWithGlide(context, holder.mImageViewContactItem, uri, defaultImagePath,
                            errorImagePath);


public  void loadImageWithGlide(final Context context, ImageView theImageViewToLoadImage,
                                          String theLoadImagePath, int theDefaultImagePath, int tehErrorImagePath) {
        if (context == null) return;

        Glide.with(context) //passing context
                .load(theLoadImagePath) //passing your url to load image.
                .placeholder(theDefaultImagePath) //this would be your default image (like default profile or logo etc). it would be loaded at initial time and it will replace with your loaded image once glide successfully load image using url.
                .error(tehErrorImagePath)//in case of any glide exception or not able to download then this image will be appear . if you won't mention this error() then nothing to worry placeHolder image would be remain as it is.
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL) //using to load into cache then second time it will load fast.
                //.animate(R.anim.fade_in) // when image (url) will be loaded by glide then this face in animation help to replace url image in the place of placeHolder (default) image.
                //.fitCenter()//this method help to fit image into center of your ImageView
                .into(theImageViewToLoadImage); //pass imageView reference to appear the image.

        /*  Normal way to Load Image with Glide.
                Glide.with(theContext)
                .load(theImagePath)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(theImageView);*/
    }
```